# Python fbs - module imports don't work after freeze

Tags: python, import, freeze

I made an application with fbs and pyqt5. 
If I execute `python3 -m fbs run` the application starts without problems.
However if I run `python3 -m fbs freeze` and execute the created executable (./myprogram), the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python/main.py", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'controller'
[28713] Failed to execute script main
```

This is how my main.py file looks like:

```
from fbs_runtime.application_context import ApplicationContext
from controller import FieldPresenter

import sys

class AppContext(ApplicationContext):
...
```

This is my folder structure:

```
python:
    - main.py
    controller:
        - __init__.py
        - FieldPresenter.py
```

This is the **init**.py in the folder controller:

```
from .FieldPresenter import FieldPresenter
```

The other **init**.py is empty

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue. Then I fixed it by removing the `__init__.py` in the `python` directory.